# How do I display two different calendars exclusively on 2 different widget?

Tags: calendar, app-widgets, google-calendar

How do I display two different calendars exclusively from my Google calendar on 2 different mobile app widget?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible as mentioned in [Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/Jh-WNWqQdTk;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/category$3Aother|sort:relevance|spell:false)- though that's about two years old

You would need a third party widget for that- see Izzy's [Calendar widgets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_widgets) collection. I tried [Widget What and When Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.whatandwhen.lite) and it works fine with two different calendars in two widgets

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, you are genius. Thanks a ton.